# Linker error while adding libRxAutomationUni_411.a library

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I am being thrown an error while building my application post adding the libRxAutomation library. I have followed the instructions that are given in their website to integrate the library, moreover it is similar to adding an external library like test flight sdk, flurry etc.

App name * app scheme is replaced with *****.. Because of few reasons I am not able to reveal the name. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

People suggested to check if any file is missing/ are added twice, I have checked in my project and every file is added only once...

```
    Ld /Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/******-internal\ Beta\ Test.app/******-internal\ Beta\ Test normal i386
        cd /Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******
        setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
        setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/****** -L\\\"/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******/******/External\\\ Libraries/Flurry\\\" -L\\\"/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******/******/External\\\ Libraries/TestFlight\\\ SDK\\\" -L/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/****** -L/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******/******/External\ Libraries/TestFlight\ SDK -F/Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/****** -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******/******/External\ Libraries/DTRichTextEditor.embeddedframework -F/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******/******/External\ Libraries/DTRichTextEditor -F/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/******/../../../../../../Downloads -filelist /Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Intermediates/******.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/******-internal\ Beta\ Test.build/Objects-normal/i386/******-internal\ Beta\ Test.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -lz.1.2.5 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libDTRichTextEditor.a -framework CoreText -framework MessageUI -framework StoreKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework GameKit -framework ImageIO -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -lxml2 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lRxAutomationUni_411 -framework SystemConfiguration -lFlurry -lTestFlight -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Intermediates/******.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/******-internal\ Beta\ Test.build/Objects-normal/i386/******-internal\ Beta\ Test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dinakarsoma2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-blnbgtkobwzputaagcrtirppgsho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/******-internal\ Beta\ Test.app/******-internal\ Beta\ Test

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L\"/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/*****/*****/External\ Libraries/Flurry\"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L\"/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/*****/*****/External\ Libraries/TestFlight\ SDK\"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/dinakarsoma2/Desktop/Patches_test/3.0/*****/../../../../../../Downloads'
ld: library not found for -lFlurry
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As anyone faced a silmilar issue.. Plz help me with your thoughts. The issue looks a small one but I am struck with this for the past couple of hours.

Any help is appreciated.. thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not able to find an actual error message among the stuff you quoted.  What is it saying is wrong?

Comment: @Phillip Mills I have edited my question.. could you plz once again peep into the log. Sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: OK, so it can't find the library directories you're trying to point it at.  Use the Terminal application to verify that they actually exist at the location given in the error messages and with the selection of quotes and slashes you're using.

Comment: @Phillip Mills I have confirmed the files exist at the locations mentioned in the error log..I am using test flight & flurry SDK's in my project and suspect those libraries are leading to a conflict.I think I am missing something in the settings of the application..any help is really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the issue... The issue was a very silly one..

Posting the same here if by any chance if someone else gets struck with a similar issue..

In Build settings -> Search Paths - The path for external providers (My case - Testflight,flurry etc). In the path the there is a space which is encoded and replaced with "\",etc.

I have removed extra character in the path which solved my issue..

ex:my path - "$(SRCROOT)/*TargetName*/External Libraries/TestFlight SDK"

its encoded as "$(SRCROOT)/*TargetName*/External Libraries/TestFlight \SDK"

removing the "\" solved the case..